# Utilizar component para todas las vistas

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Tengo un problema, estoy utilizando `vue-router` y necesito que mi `<top-bar/>` siempre se muestre en todas las vistas que van en vue router, intente utilizar:

```
<div class="container">
   <router-view name="topbar">
        <top-bar/>
   </router-view>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

tambien:

```
<div class="container">
        <top-bar/>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Quiero que mi `top-bar` quede separado de las vistas principales que se mostraran en `vue-router` asi no afectara nada.

app.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
let routes = [
    { path: '/inicio',            component: require('./components/app/PrincipalComponent.vue') },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes 
})

//Componentes ::
Vue.component('top-bar', require('./components/app/TopBarComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

**Como podría hacer que mi top-bar no entre dentro del `router-view`?**

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar tenes que crear el componente `BarraNavegacion.vue` en el directorio `components`

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li>Inicio</li>
    <li>Productos</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

En segundo lugar crear una vista (`views/InicioVista.vue`) que es lo que se va a mostrar dentro del `<router-view />`

```
<template>
  <h1>Vista inicio</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style></style>
```

En tercer lugar en el componente `App.vue`, hay que importar y instanciar la barra de navegación dentro del template. Luego, instanciar el componente `<router-view />`.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <BarraNavegacion />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BarraNavegacion from "./components/BarraNavegacion.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    BarraNavegacion
  }
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

En cuarto lugar, creas una nueva instancia del Vue-router y configuras una ruta para cada vista.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import InicioVista from "../src/views/InicioVista.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

const rutas = [{ name: "inicio", path: "/", component: InicioVista }];

export default new Router({ routes: rutas });
```

Por último, creas una instancia de Vue y injectas la instancia del router. Es importante registrar el componente `App.vue` y llamarlo en el template de la instancia Vue, ya que es el que tiene el `<router-view/>`.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>",
  router
});
```